# ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework

[image: error image]

I was trying to install daphne===4.0.0 but I keep getting this error,

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport

    Building wheels for collected packages: twisted-iocpsupport
  Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport
ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0  or higher

Comment: We had not done a release of this module for python 3.11 yet. I just saw this question kicked off the release process for 1.0.3, which should have wheels uploaded to PyPI within the hour, and you won't see this any more.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/twisted-iocpsupport/),

> Applications must not import names from the twisted_iocpsupport package directly.

So, if you're using any file with package versioning (requirements.txt, project.toml, etc.), you should remove-it manually.

Comment: This solved my issue. Using `pip freeze` after installing scrapy generates a dependency list with `twisted_iocpsupport` pinned, removing the dependency from requirements.txt fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because twisted-iocpsupport is not supported by python 3.11
Consider going back to any versions between 3.6 and 3.10
that fixed the problem for me.
Go to twisted-iocpsupport  documentation and see the versions of python it supports