# Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, python-packaging

I am trying to install scrapy using pip but this happened. I already have a virtualenv and all.

```
Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\twisted_iocpsupport
     
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport
Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport
ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried installing Twisted and twisted-iocpsupport using pip but the same problem still occurred. What should I do? I am using Python 3.11.2.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75089137/error-failed-building-wheel-for-twisted-iocpsupport

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [a comment on the related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75089137/error-failed-building-wheel-for-twisted-iocpsupport#comment133868703_75089137):

> We had not done a release of this module for python 3.11 yet. I just saw this question kicked off the release process for 1.0.3, which should have wheels uploaded to PyPI within the hour, and you won't see this any more.

In the future when you see this type of error feel free to [file a bug on Twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/issues/new/choose) to prompt one of the maintainers to upload wheels.